# Combine one value from an array to all the values of another array php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

For the building of a url query I need to combine one value(key) of an array to all the values(value) of another array. Each combined key => value needs to be added to an array.

The problem here is that I can combine the values of the two arrays in two foreach statements, but it creates for every instance a new array.

**Update**
Having duplicates is impossible so mine initial output is correct.

> $array1 array(
>
> [0] => music
>
> [1] => product
>
> )
>
> $array2 array(
>
> [0] =>  '));waitfor delay '0:0:**TIME**'--1
>
> [1] => '[TAB]or[TAB]sleep(**TIME**)='
>
> )

```
public static function create_combined_array($array1, $array2)
{
    $newArray = array();

    foreach ($array1 as $key){

      //key = [music]

      foreach ($array2 as $value) {

        //one of the values is = '));waitfor delay '0:0:__TIME__'--1

        array_push($newArray, [$key => $value]);

       }
    }


    return $newArray;
}
```

Implementation

```
$query_array = Utils::create_combined_array($params, $payload_lines);
print_r($query_array);

$query = http_build_query($query_array);

$this->url = $baseUrl . '?' . $query;
```

> Build query output
>
> protocol://localhost:8000?music='));waitfor delay '0:0:**TIME**'--1

Sample output

```
    [54] => Array
        (
            [music] => ));waitfor delay '0:0:__TIME__'--[LF]1

        )

    [55] => Array
        (
            [music] => '));waitfor delay '0:0:__TIME__'--1

        )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [music] => '));waitfor delay '0:0:__TIME__'--[LF]1

        )

    [57] => Array
        (
            [music] => "));waitfor delay '0:0:__TIME__'--1

        )
```

What I wanted to achieve is impossible in PHP.

Example duplicates

```
Array(

  [music] => "));waitfor delay '0:0:__TIME__'--1
  [music] => '/**/or/**/benchmark(10000000,MD5(1))#1

)
```

Comment: in the second foreach try to do $newArray[$key][]=$value

Comment: `array_merge` might be worth a look :)

Comment: So you want to use array1 as key and array2 as value?

Comment: @AnkitSingh for each value in array1 put all values from value 2 in it

Comment: @Cr1xus The solution gives me this as output `[music] => Array ( [0] => sleep(__TIME__) [1] => 1 or sleep(__TIME__)#1 )`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate keys in Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900276/duplicate-keys-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code below:

```
public static function create_combined_array($array1, $array2)
{
    $newArray = array();

    foreach ($array1 as $key){
        foreach ($array2 as $i => $value) {
            $newArray[$i][$key] = $value;
         }
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

The key line is `$newArray[$i][$key] = $value;`. It appends an array to the `$newArray` at `$i` index which is the index of your second array `$array2`.

Comment: Yup, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: I works but it generates this `[0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => value ) )`. See Question for expected output

Comment: Outputs `[0] => Array
        (
            [key] => value
        )  [1] => Array
        (
            [key] => value
        ) `

Comment: But you know that you can't have two same keys in one array? You can't have [0] => Array ( [key1] => value, [key1] => other_value ). That's impossible in PHP

Comment: But with scalar it is possible

Comment: You are right https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879132/php-associative-array-duplicate-keys

Comment: My initial output was actually the same as with the output of your code

Comment: You can try using index of the first array if that's what you need. Instead of having `$i => ` before `$value`, move it before `$key`

Comment: I try it and it gives me the same output as the one in my question. `foreach ($array1 as $i => $key){
         foreach ($array2 as $j => $value) {
             $newArray[$j][$key] = $value;
            }
        }`

Comment: instead of `$j` use `$i` in `$newArray[...`

Comment: This doesn't give the correct output, but I manage to fixed the problem of building the query with the "Sample output" in the Question. Thank you for your support Albert!